# How to position 2nd element center when 1st element pushing to right in CSS

Tags: css

I am very new to CSS and I created a call directory that displays a icon at left side and name of the person next to it. In next line i am printing his phone number. Phone number is aligned to center, but the name is not always.

To make it center I wrapped all my content in a div

```
<div class="container thumbnails" id="all1" tabindex="5000" align="center">
</div>
```

I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rajeevgurram/LmU5a/

How can I center the name of the person when that little icon pushing the name to right ?

Answer (score 0):

As you learn more, you'll find you rarely want to use an actual img tag. In this case, the image should be a background on the element it's next to. This way, you can position it wherever you want without it pushing around your content. While you're changing it, you may want to make the markup more semantic (simple as possible and defined by function rather than style). I suggest something like:

HTML

```
<dl>
  <dt><a href="#">Name 1</a></dt>
  <dd>Description 1</dd>
  <dt><a href="#">Name 2</a></dt>
  <dd>Description 2</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
dt {
  background: url('icon.png') no-repeat left center;
}
```